# Converting an object into another object

Tags: javascript

I need to convert below object into another object to make it compatible with elasticsearch DSL. I tried various approaches but none seems to return the exact result.
The main issue which I have is converting objects with common keys into an array. Here is my data :

```
[
   {
      "must":{
         "match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "should":{
         "match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "should":{
         "match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I need this to be converted into the below format :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
       "match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }
      },
      "should" : [
        {"match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }},
        {"match":{
            "customer_name":{
               "query":"",
               "operator":"and"
            }
         }},
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"should" : [
        "match":{` does not sees to be a valid syntax

Comment: ...because arrays may not contain keys.

Comment: its an object..my bad...updated question

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much information about your problem but this snippet works for your dataset. `ìnputJSON` is a JSON file containing your data.

```
var resultJSON = {}
resultJSON["query"]={}
resultJSON["query"]["bool"] = {}
resultJSON["query"]["bool"]["should"] = []
resultJSON["query"]["bool"]["must"] = {}
resultJSON["query"]["bool"]["minimum_should_match"] = 1
var source = inputJSON
source.forEach(currentElement =>{
    if(currentElement["must"]!=undefined){
        resultJSON["query"]["bool"]["must"] = currentElement["must"]
    }
    if(currentElement["should"]!=undefined){
        resultJSON["query"]["bool"]["should"].push(currentElement["should"])
    }
})
```

Returns :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "customer_name": {
              "query": "",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customer_name": {
              "query": "",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "customer_name": {
            "query": "",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = [
  {
    "must":{
        "match":{
          "customer_name":{
              "query":"",
              "operator":"and"
          }
        }enter code here

    },
  },
  {
    "should":{
        "match":{
          "customer_name":{
              "query":"",
              "operator":"and"
          }
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "should":{
        "match":{
          "customer_name":{
              "query":"",
              "operator":"and"
          }
        }
    }
  }
]
let resultTemplate = {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {},
      should: [],
      minimum_should_match: 1,
    },
  },
};

const converter = (source) => {
  source.forEach((item) => {
    let iKeys = Object.keys(item);
    iKeys.forEach((key) => {
      if (key === 'must') {
        resultTemplate.query.bool[key] = item[key];
      } else {
        resultTemplate.query.bool[key].push(item[key]);
      }
    });
  });
};

converter(obj);
console.log(resultTemplate);
```

Comment: thanks...this helped a lot....can't believe it was this simple...and here i was trying all sorts of manipulations